# PHP cURL connection refused on localhost

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I'm trying to execute a cURL request in PHP to my localhost, but I get the following error:

> cURL error (7): Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

I've tried to Google this message, and also found similar questions on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to be working.

**curl.php:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost:8000/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL error (' . curl_errno($ch) . '): ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

**test.php:**

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "message" => "Hello World!"
));
```

If I remove the "**CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE**" value, the request never resolves. I've also tried setting both "**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**" and "**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**" to false. Still not working.

But if I navigate to localhost:8000/test.php in my browser, I get the correct response. I can also use the "**curl localhost:8000/test.php**" command and receive the correct response

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you are using linux, make sure the server is running using 
/etc/init.d/httpd status

Comment: I'm using Windows and WAMP. But it shows all services are running. I've also tried restarting it. Same problem

Comment: use full URL "http://localhost:8000/test.php" with http://

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the http:// in the begining of the request like  Rahul Prajapati wrote you in a comment

see this other post
[PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

note this line uses
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");

the thing is, if you put in your browser localhost:8000/test.php, the browser will put the protocol by default and it will appear that you are making the same call and getting diferents outputs

Hope this helps you